# Sharepoint 2013 TLS 1.2 SQL Native client issue

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sql, sql-server-2012, tls

I've been following the below guide for updating to TLS 1.2.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/security-for-sharepoint-server/enable-tls-and-ssl-support-in-sharepoint-2013

I am working to install the SQL Native client update on my SP servers but when I run any of the installers it says it is not supported by my operating system. I am running Windows Server 2012r2

My current version of snac is 10.51.2500.0

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/security-for-sharepoint-server/enable-tls-and-ssl-support-in-sharepoint-2013#14---install-sql-server-2008-r2-native-client-update-for-tls-12-support

My current farm is:
1 WFE
2 APP
1 DB - Running SQL 2014 sp2